# How to implement Google Ad Manager (aka DFP) in a gatsby site?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, google-dfp, google-ad-manager, google-publisher-tag

In order to serve GAM/DFP ads on a gastby.js site, I am supposed to put this code in the head:

```
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
      window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.defineSlot('/22274312948/lm1_lb1', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1614985862735-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
      });
</script>
```

And this code in the body, where I want to show the ad:

```
<!-- /22274312948/lm1_lb1 -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1614985862735-0' style='width: 728px; height: 90px;'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1614985862735-0'); });
  </script>
</div>
```

My gatsby site is based on MDX files, and I would like to place ads between the paragraphs, by calling them from the MDX file itself.

Answer (score 2):

The `<head>` script can be placed in any React (so Gatsby) application using the [`<Helmet>`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) component. Basically, all it is wrapped inside, it's placed in the `<head>` of your application. So, in any component, for example, the `<Layout>` you can:

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return <section>
    <Helmet>
      <script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
      <script>
      {`window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.defineSlot('/22274312948/lm1_lb1', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1614985862735-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
      });`}
      </script>
    </Helmet>
    <Header />
    <main>{children}</main>
  </section>;
};
```

Be careful when [dealing with global objects such as `window` or `document` in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) outside React's lifecycle, it may lead to hydration issues and caveats. Therefore, some of them are not available during the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) If you can use a Gatsby plugin rather than adding the script manually, I would strongly suggest doing it, for example, using the [`gatsby-plugin-google-adsense`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/@isamrish/gatsby-plugin-google-adsense/?=gatsby-plugin-google-adsens), simply using:

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `@isamrish/gatsby-plugin-google-adsense`,
      options: {
        googleAdClientId: "YOUR_GOOGLE_ADSENSE_TRACKING_ID",
        head: false // Optional
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Regarding your MDX script, since your MDX files allow you to embed JSX logic (hence the name) you just can add it wherever you want:

```
import { Box, Heading, Text } from 'somewhere'

# Here is a JSX block

It is using imported components!

<Box>
  <Heading>Here's a JSX block</Heading>
  <Text>It's pretty neat</Text>
  <YourScriptComponent />
</Box>
```

In your `YourScriptComponent.js` you can just add your script like any other component, something like:

```
const YourScriptComponent = () =>{

return <>
    <!-- /22274312948/lm1_lb1 -->
    <div id='div-gpt-ad-1614985862735-0' style='width: 728px; height: 90px;'>
      <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1614985862735-0'); });
      </script>
    </div>
</>
}
```

---

Updating the issue with the final fix for those who may help. The above workaround shows the path to add a GAM ad in a Gatsby/React site. The idea is to use the MDX to import a custom component that loads a promised-based component/module that contains the ad itself. Something like:

```
---

import DFPWrapper from '../../../src/components/DFPWrapper';

This is the body of the markdown

<DFPWrapper />
```

There, you can import an own or a third-party dependency, such as [`react-gpt`](https://github.com/nfl/react-gpt):

```
const DFPWrapper = props => {
  return <>
    <Helmet>
      <script async src='https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js' />
      <script>
        {`window.googletag = window.googletag || { cmd: [] };
          googletag.cmd.push(function() {
          googletag.defineSlot('/22274312948/lm1_lb1', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1614985862735-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
          googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
          googletag.enableServices();`}
      </script>
    </Helmet>
    <div>
      <GPT adUnitPath='/22274312948/lm1_lb1' slotSize={[728, 90]} />
    </div>
  </>
}
```

The information required for the react-gpt is stored in this line:

```
googletag.defineSlot('/22274312948/lm1_lb1', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1614985862735-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

Comment: Thanks! When I edit my layout.js following your answer, I'm getting a syntax error ( '}' expected. ) for the colon in {cmd: []}, as this is not valid JSX (I think...). Any idea what can I do about that?

Comment: I had a typo, wrap the script between {` `}

Comment: I've updated with the final fix @TheRose :)